# How to detect who is talking WebRTC stream swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing an ios application using webRTC for establishing meeting. I want to detect who is talking in the webRTC streams by using swift please.

Comment: Any idea to detect who is speaking by using webRtc stream

Answer (score 1):

You have to poll the stats after some time, maybe 5 milliseconds or 1 second that is up to you.

This answer is for a one-to-one chat. However, I don't have any idea how to fix it in multi-user chat.

```
peerConnection.statistics { [weak self] report in
            let statistics = report.statistics
            for case let stat in statistics.values {
                switch stat.type {
                case "media-source":
                    // From this I will get my own audio level
                    let level = (stat.values["audioLevel"] as? Double) ?? .zero
                case "track":
                    // From this I will get other party's audio level 
                    let level = (stat.values["audioLevel"] as? Double) ?? .zero
                default:
                    continue
                }
            }
        }
```